# Terraform module to create S3 bucket for lambda function which is accessible cross account?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am new to Terraform and I am trying to create a Terraform module S3 bucket for Lambda function which is accessible cross account. Also the Cross account access should be limited to listing and getting objects.

Below is what I get to create lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename         = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  s3_bucket        = "my_bucket_name"
  function_name    = "lambda_function_name"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "exports.test"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function_payload.zip"))}"
  runtime          = "nodejs4.3"
}
```

This is how my s3 bucket code looks like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "log"
    enabled = true

    prefix = "log/"

    tags {
      "rule"      = "log"
      "autoclean" = "true"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 30
      storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 60
      storage_class = "GLACIER"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 90
    }
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "tmp"
    prefix  = "tmp/"
    enabled = true

    expiration {
      date = "2016-01-12"
    }
  }

  #Using this section for cors_rule
  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["GET"]
    allowed_origins = ["https://s3-website-test.hashicorp.com"]
  }
}
```

How I can turn this into a module ?

Answer (score 1):

The necessary policies are described in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html). In the following I will describe how to setup this example with a single terraform module - you have to adjust the permissions to your needs. You can also extend it, to support more than 2 AWS accounts. I haven't run the following code myself, so there might be some typos etc., but it should help you to get the general idea behind it.

Lets assume AWS account A is the account your s3 bucket is in and AWS account B is the account your lambda function is running in.

In order to place everything into a single module, you must define 2 Terraform AWS providers; one for each AWS account involved.

```
// Your s3 bucket's provider - used by default
provider "aws" {
  .. // your setup here
}

// Your lambda function's provider - used if specified via alias
provider "aws" {
  .. // your setup here

  alias = "lambda"
}
```

First, attach a policy to your s3 bucket to allow access from account B:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "lambda" {
  provider = "aws.lambda"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_cross_account" {
  policy_id = "Cross account access for s3"

  statement {
    sid= "1"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.lambda.account_id}:root"]
    }

    actions    = [""s3:GetBucketLocation", "s3:ListBucket"]
    resources  = ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_cross_account" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_cross_account.json}"
}
```

Next, in AWS account B create a role which can be used by your lambda function:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "access_cross_account_s3" {
  provider = "aws.lambda"

  policy_id = "Cross account access for s3"

  statement {
    sid= "1"

    actions    = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources  = ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_cross_account" {
  provider = "aws.lambda"

  name = "s3_cross_account"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.access_cross_account_s3.json}"
}
```

Your lambda function code block must also have the `provider = "aws.lambda"` config set, so it is created in AWS account B.